# Increasing swap space without reinstallation

Tags: fedora, swap

I'm running Fedora 20, and I forgot to change my swap size allocation during installation.  I have 16G of RAM, so I'd like to allocate 32G of swap space.  The install created a swap for me, of only 8G.  The Fedora install is on an LVM2 partition.

Is there a way I can increase the swap size without reinstalling Fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes.

Install the latest version of the `gparted` utility and resize your partitions appropriately. If you downsize one of your other partitions and then upsize your swap partition, the new swap size will automatically become available to the operating system.

Comment: So, it seems there is no actual swap partition?  According to GParted, /dev/sda3 is lvm2 pv filesystem.  Disks, however, tells me there's a 8 GB Block Device, which is an Active Swap at /dev/mapper/fedora-swap.  I'm not sure what this means, exactly.

Comment: It could be that, on older packaged versions of gparted, you cannot resize the LVM partition. You'll need, then, to do it via command line. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/394105/how-to-resize-partition-that-is-inside-linux-lvm-partition -- also, you might want to consider whether this is necessary. Most swap partitions are hardly used with that amount of RAM...

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I tried resizing with lvresize (removing from home and adding to swap), but I kept getting into emergency mode, and e2fsck indicated a sizing issue on home.  I put things back the way they were and moved on.  I think you're right, with that much RAM, it's not worth the headache to me.